# Setting NGINX TLS with certificate/key loaded by initContainer

Tags: azure, ssl, nginx, kubernetes

I've found several pages describing how to set `NGINX` to use HTTPS/TLS.
However, all suggest setting a `secret tls` with the key & cert.
We want to be able to use TLS but ask NGINX to load the key/cert via [init-container](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/) which in this case implemented by [acs-keyvault-agent](https://github.com/Hexadite/acs-keyvault-agent).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If your only goal is to obtain the TLS key/cert from Azure Key Vault, then you're probably better of going with the [Key Vault FlexVolume](https://github.com/Azure/kubernetes-keyvault-flexvol) project from Azure. This would have the advantage of not using init containers at all and just dealing with volumes and volume mounts.

Since you explicitly want to use [Hexadite/acs-keyvault-agent](https://github.com/Hexadite/acs-keyvault-agent) and in default mode (which uses volume mounts btw) there is a full example of how to do this in the projects examples folder here: [examples/acs-keyvault-deployment.yaml#L40-L47](https://github.com/Hexadite/acs-keyvault-agent/blob/master/examples/acs-keyvault-deployment.yaml#L40-L47).

Obviously you need to build, push, and configure the container correctly for your environment. Then you will need to conifgure Nginx to use the `CertFileName.pem` and `KeyFilename.pem` from the `/secrets/certs_keys/` folder.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, we've considered using FlexVolume but it has other disadvantages. That's not the question here :) This way or another, I can't see how using FlexVolume will help to answer my question as it will mount a secret to a volume in a similar way

Comment: Okay let's take a step back, how do you plan to configure/deploy acs-keyvault-agent? Specifically will it be in default mode, or in cron mode?

Comment: Default mode. The idea is retrieving the certs from Azure KeyVault directly without the need to create a script which downloads the certs and creates a tls secret